# Finding Records +/- 5 seconds of a Datetime

Tags: sql-server, t-sql

Noticed some data errors in a table of mine where there are duplicated records but within a few seconds of eachother in a datetime field.

Eg.

```
|-------------------|----------------|--------------------------|
|     ProductID     |   SourceID     |          Datetime        |
|-------------------|----------------|--------------------------|
|         1234      |        99      |  2020-08-11 00:00:01 000 |
|-------------------|----------------|--------------------------|
|         1234      |        99      |  2020-08-11 00:00:02 000 |
|-------------------|----------------|--------------------------|
```

I know for a fact this data is wrong, and shouldn't be possible. To find all possible cases of this, I want to select distinct ProductIDs and SourceID which have multiple rows within 5 seconds of each other. How would I write the SQL for datetimes with a 5 second +/i?

Comment: How do you tell what the "originating" row is? Is it always the first? What happens if you have a row, that has a duplicate that is 4 seconds later, which has another 4 seconds after that, and then another another 4 seconds later. Is that row that is 12 seconds later a duplicate of the first still?

Comment: Great question. I am happy with saying that if it falls outside of 15 seconds overall, than it's safe.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I came up with something that should work with what you need to find out. It will return a distinct list of `ProductID,SourceID` that were inserted within 5 seconds of the previous entry. I used [LAG](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/sql/t-sql/functions/lag-transact-sql?view=sql-server-ver15) and [DATEDIFF](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/sql/t-sql/functions/datediff-transact-sql?view=sql-server-ver15) in the query.

I just saw you would be satisfied to search records inserted with 15 seconds. If so, change `DATEDIFF(s,PreviousValue,[DateTime]) <= 5` in the second CTE to `DATEDIFF(s,PreviousValue,[DateTime]) <= 15`

```
--Get Value Of Previous Record
WITH preselect AS
(
    SELECT ProductID
           ,SourceID
           ,[DateTime]
           ,LAG([DateTime],1,NULL) OVER(PARTITION BY ProductId,SourceId ORDER BY [DateTime]) AS 'PreviousValue'
    FROM [yourTable]
),

--Find the difference in time
preselect2 AS
(
    SELECT ProductID
           ,SourceID
           ,DATEDIFF(s,PreviousValue,[DateTime]) AS 'SecondDifference'
    FROM preselect
    WHERE PreviousValue IS NOT NULL
          AND
          DATEDIFF(s,PreviousValue,[DateTime]) <= 5
)

/*Get Distinct list of ProductID,SourceID that were inserted within 5 seconds of the
previous entry*/
SELECT DISTINCT ProductID,SourceID
FROM preselect2
```